# deleteRow (Java MySQL connector not working)

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

i'm new to mysql and i'm trying to delete a row after i redeem the code. I did deleteRow and did commit but it isn't working.

Here's my code, do you see anything wrong with it?

```
try (Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test", "root", "")) {
                        Statement stmt= con.createStatement();
                        ResultSet r= stmt.executeQuery("SELECT gennedkey FROM `keys` WHERE gennedkey='" + message[1] + "'");
                        while(r.next())
                        {
                            
                            EmbedBuilder verifiedroleembed = new EmbedBuilder();
                            verifiedroleembed.setTitle("Verified");
                            verifiedroleembed.setColor(Color.green);
                            
                            event.getChannel().sendMessage(verifiedroleembed.build()).queue();
                            event.getMessage().delete().complete();
                            
                            r.deleteRow();
                            con.commit();
                        }
                       
                        
                        con.close();
                    } catch (SQLException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
```

Comment: Delete row will only work on result sets that have been created by statements that were explicitly marked updatable. Also, committing while iterating over a result set is not the proper way: commit **after** the loop. As far as I know, MySQL Connector/J will actually throw an exception that explains the problem and how to solve it.

Comment: As an aside, please learn about prepared statements and parameters. Concatenating values into a query string makes your code vulnerable to SQL injection.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't say what "didn't work" means, but since you are trying to delete a set of rows, this might be a problem with some older MySQL Connector/J versions. When you call `deleteRow`, the cursor is advanced, and then you call `next` (at the top of your loop) and you skip the next record without deleting it. This is definitely surprising.

Here is the bug report against Connector/J:
https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=27431

The solution is to work around the bug like this:

```
    int rowNum = rs.getRow();
    rs.deleteRow();

    if(rowNum == rs.getRow())
        rs.previous();
```

This solution will work with both the old (broken?) and newer versions of Connector/J.